# How do I change Font size in VS Code Sidebars and Topbars

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My vs code editor top bar and left sidebar menu font are decreased. I tried to increase the fonts size but the side and top bar fonts are still remain same.

[image: VS COde]

Answer (score 6):

Use Keyboard shortcut

Zoom in : `ctrl + +`

Zoom out : `ctrl + -`

Comment: to zoom out `ctrl shift +` worked for me